# Odoo-9 server consumption cost on Azure

Tags: azure, odoo, odoo-9, energy, consumption

I recently installed an Odoo-9 server on Azure.
The consumption was extremely high (150$ in 10 days).
Is it something usual?
Do you have an estimation about the consumption cost (processor & RAM)?
Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of the resources you are using. There is the [Azure resources calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/) you can use to estimate resources pricing.
150$/10 days is something that is similar to virtual machine. 
Also, you can see the pricing breakout in your account (right corner of the screen, Bill button).